# Special immunity that newspapers do not enjoy

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law

Pai said in a statement Thursday.

> “Social media companies have a First Amendment right to free speech.
> But they do not have a First Amendment right to a special immunity
> denied to other media outlets, such as newspapers and broadcasters.”

This is in regards to regulating "social media" outlets.

What immunity do newspapers NOT have that the likes of Facebook enjoy?
I ask, because I was under the understanding that a newspaper would be enjoying greater freedoms, as they have very explicit first amendment protection.

Note this question is in law section, only interested in how newspapers are regulated, whereas "social media" companies are not. What greater freedoms do these companies enjoy.

Comment: @Trish Pai (Ajit Pai) is the chairman of the FCC. The "First Amendment" regarding free speech is the US Constitution, since the other ones do not have that as a first amendment. You can reasonably conclude that this question is focusing on the US Constitution/law...

Comment: @RonBeyer I always ask if it is not specifically mentioned anywhere, as I am certainly not sure which other constitutions might have as structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The additional protections for social-media platforms comes from Section 230 of the Communications Decency Act, not from the First Amendment.

[Section 230](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/47/230) basically provides immunity from defamation and other kinds of liability. Generally speaking, it applies only to platforms, i.e., companies providing a service for *other people* to create and post content. This goes beyond social-media companies to include message boards, blogging platforms, dating websites, etc.

Newspapers generally do not enjoy this protection because the information that they post on their websites is information that they have generated themselves.

Comment: Interactive computer services...Washington Post could create a service and post only their content as well as non-commercial user-generated content?

Comment: This is 95% accurate, so +1, but the issue of current debate is whether full editorial discretion is what distinguishes newspapers from the social media companies.  This is different from "the information which they generate themselves" because a great portion of many newspapers' content is created by 3rd parties.  For example, they reprint licensed content from AP and Reuters verbatim.

Comment: @grovkin: Well, if newspapers do so *on the internet*, then they are indeed subject to section 230. The law is very broadly written. It would even cover things like letters to the editor, which usually are heavily moderated. The newspapers only lose this immunity when they print the material out and mail it to people.

Comment: @grovkin I don't see how the distinction between newspapers and social-media companies is relevant for Section 230 purposes. The relevant distinction is between "content providers" (who create information) and computer services (which allow other people to access other providers' content).

Comment: @bdb484 i don't think 230 gives newspapers immunity if they print libelous content they licensed from someone else.  but *i don't know*... there i said it.  I assume they don't. At least that's how it's *generally* described when it is publically debated.  I am not trying to argue *my* position here... only to describe what's the issue of contention.

Comment: @Kevin that's an interesting take. I haven't seen anyone else make this claim.  This in itself doesn't make it wrong, of course.

Comment: @grovkin: I really don't see how else you can read the plain text of [paragraph (c) subparagraph (1)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/47/230). It is one sentence long, and does not say anything that I read as exempting newspapers (or anyone else, for that matter). As long as the material was "provided by another information content provider," the service provider (newspaper, or whoever) appears to be immune. There is then a *separate* waiver for moderation actions in (c)(2).

Comment: @Kevin as it is written, it is indeed very broad.  I don't know if the regulators have the power to clarify this though.  There is no question that in reality a newspaper printing AP articles acts as a publisher.  Maybe "interactive" is the key distinction.  There is nothing interactive about an article which a newspaper reprints.  I am sure it's possible to make an argument to the contrary, but I am not trying to argue what's the correct interpretation here.  I just think the answer should convey what the issues of contention are.

Comment: @grovkin: There's no wiggle room in "interactive" - see (f)(2) for its definition: "**any information service**, system, or access software provider **that provides or enables computer access by multiple users to a computer server**, including specifically a service or system that provides access to the Internet and such systems operated or services offered by libraries or educational institutions." You can't run a website, of any kind whatsoever, without satisfying that definition.

Comment: @Kevin your argument amount to saying that there *shouldn't* be a controversy.  But the controversy exists.  However strong your argument maybe, it's not with me.

Comment: @grovkin: This is law.SE, not politics.SE. And from a legal perspective, there basically isn't any controversy. Read through [some of the case law](https://www.eff.org/issues/cda230/legal) to get a better understanding of this. In short, 230 has been applied to a panoply of different situations, companies, and business models, and there is nothing in either case law or statutory law that would limit its application to social media sites.

Comment: I've also wondered the same thing about whether printing wire reports triggers Section 230 immunity. I've never seen an anwer, and I suspect that it may be because you don't need to reach the question because many states recognize a "wire service privilege," which is basically Section 230 protection for newspapers printing wire content.

Comment: @Kevin I took your suggestion and tried to look through [case law on the EFF's site](https://www.eff.org/issues/cda230/legal).  The very first case at the top (Anthony v. Yahoo!) said that the ninth circuit ruled that "*CDA § 230 does not apply* to content that an interactive service provider 'developed or created entirely by itself.'"  So the suggestion that 230 provides a blanket protection, as long as the medium of delivery is a website, does not seem to hold.  The issue of contention maybe whether selective editing, or fact checking, of 3rd party content is creative work.

Comment: @grovkin: That is not what I said at all. I said that it applies to companies which are not social media, and the cases that I linked to support that contention.

Comment: @Kevin in what way does the ruling that "CDA § 230 does not apply to content that an interactive service provider 'developed or created entirely by itself'" support the contention that "it applies to companies which are not social media?"

Comment: @grovkin: I cited *all* of the cases, including for example [this one](https://www.eff.org/issues/cda230/cases/blumenthal-v-drudge).